# How to convert CVPixelBufferRef from kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB to kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB

Tags: macos, uiimage, image-manipulation, quicktime

I'm a new Apple developer and I'm struggling with the different image representations...

I would Have a CVPixelBufferRef in kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB format, and I would like to create a new  kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB CVPixelBufferRef from it (i.e. discarding the alpha bits).

Is there a simple way to do it, or do I have to copy it with a 'for' loop?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.6.4, and have been working on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CaptureAndCompressIPBMovie/Listings/CaptureAndCompressIPBMovie_c.html)  sample code.

Thanks,
Pinhassi.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Accelerate framework, there is a function `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB888()` that should implement an efficient SIMD based conversion.